# Getting error after trying to harvest from geoserver into pycsw

Tags: python, geoserver, metadata, csw, pycsw

I'm using osgeo live to test the pycsw functionality. I need to harvest metadata from an existing Geoserver service (previously configure for this task).

I'm quite new with CSW and I'm not sure if my procedure is right. I've trie to follow the instrutions under:
http://geopython.github.io/pycsw-workshop/docs/intro/intro-exercises.html#metadata-harvesting

My xml config file (called 'cat.xml') for the harvest is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Harvest xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/CSW-publication.xsd" service="CSW" version="2.0.2">
    <Source>http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wms</Source>
    <ResourceType>http://www.opengis.net/wms</ResourceType>
    <ResourceFormat>application/xml</ResourceFormat>
  </Harvest>
```

for the source element I've used this one too (without exit):

```
<Source>http://localhost:8082/geoserver/cat/wms</Source>
```

I use the command:

```
$ cd /var/www/pycsw
$ python ./sbin/pycsw-admin.py -c post_xml -u http://localhost/pycsw/csw.py -x ~/cat.xml
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
Intializing static context
Executing HTTP POST request /home/user/cat.xml on server http://localhost/pycsw/csw.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sbin/pycsw-admin.py", line 245, in <module>
    print admin.post_xml(CSW_URL, XML, TIMEOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycsw/admin.py", line 506, in post_xml
    raise RuntimeError(err)
RuntimeError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

The request GetCapabilities works:

```
localhost/pycsw/csw.py?config=tests/suites/default/default.cfg&service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetCapabilites
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

`pycsw-admin.py` does not currently support proxy.  You can work around this with:

`curl -x <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]> -X POST -d @cat.xml http://localhost/pycsw/csw.py`

If this still gives you errors then this means that the proxy information has to pass through pycsw to be able to access the resource to be harvested.

If you open a [ticket](https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/issues/new) this would helpful in providing this in the next pycsw release.

Comment: Thaks Tom. I've opened a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

The response shows that the WMS has a login requirement.  What happens when you try to invoke a GetCapabilities operation against the WMS? i.e.:

`http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities`

You might also want to try some of the methods at http://pycsw.org/faq/#how-can-i-make-csw-post-xml-requests to further diagnose.

Comment: After invoke `http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities` I get the file getcapabilities_1.1.1.xml. When I invoke `http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&layers=cat:cat&styles=&bbox=-180.0,-87.0,180.0,87.0&width=682¬height=330&srs=EPSG4326¬format=image7png` I get the layer on the browser.

Comment: What happens when you try `curl -X POST -d @cat.xml http://localhost/pycsw/csw.py` ?

Comment: The response has an `Access denied (authentication_failed)`

Comment: This authentication is for the database? Or there is in some folder insufficient permissions?

Comment: The authentication is for the URL.  What happens when you try `curl http://localhost/pycsw/csw.py` ?

Comment: I get `Redirect (authetication_redirect_to_virtual_host)` and `You are being redirected to the authetication virtual host`

Comment: The proxy settings are configured. I can call external web pages.